# Pass arguments to scrapy spider through docker run

Tags: python, docker, scrapy

I have a scrapy+Selenium spider packaged in a docker container. I want to run that container with passing some aruments to the spider. However, for some reason I receive a strange error message. I did an extensive search and tried many different options before submitting the question.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# install xvfb
RUN apt-get install -yqq xvfb

# install pyvirtualdisplay
RUN pip install pyvirtualdisplay

# set display port and dbus env to avoid hanging
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null

#install scrapy
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade \
        setuptools \
        wheel && \
    pip install --upgrade scrapy

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium==3.8.0

# install xlrd
RUN pip install xlrd

# install bs4
RUN pip install beautifulsoup4

ADD . /tralala/

WORKDIR tralala/
CMD scrapy crawl personel_spider_mpc -a chunksNo=$chunksNo -a chunkI=$chunkI
```

I guess that the problem may be in CMD part.

Spider init part:

```
class Crawler(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "personel_spider_mpc"

    allowed_domains = ['tralala.de',]

    def __init__(self, vdisplay = True, **kwargs):
        super(Crawler, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.chunkI = chunkI
        self.chunksNo = chunksNo
```

How I run the container:

```
docker run --env chunksNo='10' --env chunkI='1' ostapp/tralala
```

I tried with both quotations marks and without them

The error message:

```
2018-04-04 16:42:32 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 79, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 102, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 51, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tralala/tralala/spiders/tralala_spider_mpc.py", line 673, in __init__
    self.chunkI = chunkI
NameError: global name 'chunkI' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are stored in `kwargs`, which is just a dictionary, with key acting as argument name and value as argument value. It does not define names for you, so you get your error.

For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

In your specific case, try `self.chunkI = kwargs['chunkI']` and `self.chunksNo = kwargs['chunksNo']`